# Windows hostnames in smb.conf

Tags: windows, samba, windows-10

So I'm sharing some drives(in my Ubuntu desktop) to my laptop(Windows), but I only want me to be able to access it on my local network. I got it to work by adding the following line to smb.conf `hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1.1` where 192.168.1.1 is my laptop IP(just an example). But it wont work if I use my laptop hostname instead of the IP(e.g. `hosts allow = 127. Z1-B`).

I've run `sudo apt install winbind libnss-winbind` so now I can run `ping Z1-B` which works. Unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. What can I do to allow samba on Ubuntu to convert the Windows hostname to an IP?

Answer (score 1):

To allow only people in your local network you could add under the share `hosts allow = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.` to allow your machine as well as any device on that subnet of 192.168.1. to access the share.

To allow specific hostnames you should use commas between IPs and hostnames. You can do `hosts allow = 127.0.0.1, Z1-B`

*If this helped please consider voting up*

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following:

- restart samba after changing the configuration
- add your windows laptop to the /etc/hosts file. Something like the this:

192.168.1.1          Z1-B

and after restart

Answer (score 0):

I found that placing the hostname FIRST in the hosts allow did the trick. I.e.

```
 hosts allow = Z1-B, 192. 10.     #Comma after hostname
 dns proxy = yes
 hostname lookups = yes
```

Restart Samba
...and it worked even when reverse DNS lookup of hostname (Z1-B) failed, which is great for me as my hostname is dynamicaly defined with no-ip.com

For reference, I'm using FreeBSD 12.2 with SMB 4.13.1